# What does lma mean?

Tags: gdb, embedded, openocd

When loading an executable onto a board using OpenOCD and GDB, I get something similar to (snippet taken from [here](http://openocd.sourceforge.net/doc/html/GDB-and-OpenOCD.html)):

```
 $ arm-none-eabi-gdb example.elf
 (gdb) target remote localhost:3333
 Remote debugging using localhost:3333
 ...
 (gdb) monitor reset halt
 ...
 (gdb) load
 Loading section .vectors, size 0x100 lma 0x20000000
 Loading section .text, size 0x5a0 lma 0x20000100
 Loading section .data, size 0x18 lma 0x200006a0
 Start address 0x2000061c, load size 1720
 Transfer rate: 22 KB/sec, 573 bytes/write.
 (gdb) continue
 Continuing.
 ...
```

What does `lma` mean in this context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That means "Local Memory Address", which is the address in memory where code or data has been loaded to:

http://www.embeddedrelated.com/usenet/embedded/show/77071-1.php